# добавить логирование slf4j в приложение на spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, логирование, yml, slf4j

Как добавить и настроить логирование в приложении? Приложение на spring boot, конфигурация application.yml. Куча статей и ответов на форуме как добавить в application.properties и т.п. Для yml файла ничего не нахожу.

И нужно ли кроме yml файла вносить какие-то зависимости в pom или еще что-то? На сколько я знаю в spring boot уже идет slf4j в комплекте и в pom не надо добавлять его. Но могу ошибаться.

UPD. да, действительно, зависимости добавлять не нужно.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/slf4j-with-log4j2-logback Зачем вам нужно что то в application.yml не совсем понятно, просто добавьте зависимости в pom

Comment: бред, настроить уровни логирования в pom? 
в spring boot уже идет slf4j в комплекте. не нужно зависимости добавлять вообще

Comment: Извольте соблюдать элементарную вежливость и научитесь задавать вопросы корректно, это способствует правильным ответам, знаете ли. Можете продемонстрировать где у вас в вопросе озвучено хоть что то про уровни логирования?

Comment: добавить зависимость в pom - это равно "добавить логирование в приложение"? 
и даже тут вы ошиблись и не признали это.
у меня в вопросе уже указан spring boot. с ним уже идет логирование в комплекте. и что не нужно добавлять никакие зависимости. но другой человек ниже подтвердил и я позже еще в документации прочла.  а вы написали неправильно и дезинформировали.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_skills

Comment: если это по-вашему вежливо было "Зачем вам нужно что то в application.yml не совсем понятно", чтож.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашла что искала самостоятельно. настойка уровней логирования и файла для логов.
может кому пригодиться.

```
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    com.mypackage: ERROR
  pattern:
    console: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
    file: "%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n"
  file:
    name: app.log
```

Answer (score 0):

slf4j это обобщение для некоторого колличества систем логирования. В spring boot application.properties или application.yaml указывается настройка для системы логирования которая использует slf4j.

Например вот так

```
logging:
  config: classpath:logging/log4j2-default.yml
```

настраивается конфигурация log4j 2 версии которая хранится в отдельном файле.

Основное отличие это вместо '.' ставим ':' и перенос на следующую строку с отступом.

```
logging:
  threshold:
    console: INFO
```

С зависимостями всё просто. В org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter уже есть внутри org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging с logback и slf4j